# How to import a pdf file as background to GtkDrawingArea

Tags: c, gtk3

I need to import a pdf file as background that I can draw on it. I want to some new figures and I want to highlighten some areas.

I was searching the Internet for the last three days. The only thing I found ist the opposite, writing to pdf files.

/* does the other way */
cairo_pdf_surface_create();

First I tried this command but when I realized that it's overwriting my source file instead of importing it.

I am using GTK3 and C for writing my program.

Answer (score 1):

As you've already figured out, it's not a straightforward task: GTK doesn't have PDF rendering features, so you have to use some external library.

I recommend taking a look at Evince, GTK document viewer. It has different backends for different document types. For PDF it's [`ev-poppler.cc`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/blob/gnome-3-22/backend/pdf/ev-poppler.cc) and it uses [poppler library](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/).

Inside that `ev-poppler.cc` there is [`pdf_page_render`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/blob/gnome-3-22/backend/pdf/ev-poppler.cc#L386) which renders a single page and [`pdf_document_get_page`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/blob/gnome-3-22/backend/pdf/ev-poppler.cc#L345) which gets a single page from backend.